# Discarding GLSL fragment values not working with stencil buffer

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders, glsl

I am trying to make a system where I can outline sprites, but I can only get it to work correctly when I use a regular-shaped texture. Here is what an outlined regular texture looks like:

[image: working outline]

However, here is an irregular texture with the same outline code applied to it:

[image: non-working outline]

I must say that the non-working outline *does* use modified texture coordinates, but this shouldn't matter, as all pixels with alpha = 0 are discarded (the second image is transparent around the person), which *should* prevent the stencil buffer from receiving them. However, the stencil buffer still counts the discarded pixels as "written". Here are my shaders, all of which we the same across the two textures:

Texture Vertex:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * transform * vec4(aPos, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Texture Fragment:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
uniform vec4 color;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord) * color;
    if (FragColor.a == 0) discard;
}
```

Outline Fragment (paired with texture vertex):

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec4 color;

void main() {
    fragColor = color;
    if (fragColor.a == 0) discard;
}
```

Finally, here is the shared render code:

```cpp
void c2m::client::gl::Sprite::render() {
    // Bind framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    // Resize the image buffer for different outline sizing
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texBuffer);
    sf::Vector2u size = tex->getSfTexture().lock()->getSize();
    GLuint sizeX = size.x + (GLuint)(size.x * outlineWidth * 2), sizeY = size.y + (GLuint)(size.y * outlineWidth * 2);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, sizeX, sizeY, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // Resize renderbuffer?

    // Clear framebuffer
    glClearColor(.1f, .1f, .1f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set shader uniforms if the shader is initialized
    if (shader != nullptr) {
        if (outlineWidth > 0) {
            glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
            glStencilMask(0xFF);
        }

        applyTransforms();
        shader->useShader();
        // Framebuffer will be transformed, this will not
        shader->setMat4("transform", glm::mat4(1.0f));
        shader->setVec4("color", color.asVec4());
    }

    // Rebind the VAO to be able to modify its VBOs
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Reset vertex data to class array
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // Bind texture
    tex->bind();

    // Draw
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    // If the outline width is 0 return
    if (outlineWidth == 0) {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        return;
    }

    // Draw outline
    if (outlineShader != nullptr) {
        glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
        glStencilMask(0x00);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        outlineShader->useShader();

        outlineShader->setVec4("color", outlineRGBA.asVec4());
        // Temporary transform matrix to prevent pollution of user-set transforms
        glm::mat4 tempTransform = trans;
        tempTransform = glm::scale(tempTransform, glm::vec3(outlineWidth + 1, outlineWidth + 1, outlineWidth + 1));
        tempTransform = glm::translate(tempTransform, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
        // Framebuffer will be transformed, this will not
        outlineShader->setMat4("transform", glm::mat4(1.0f));
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glStencilMask(0xFF);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    frame->useShader();
    frame->setMat4("transform", trans);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texBuffer);
    // Temporarily use old VBO, will make a new one once textures are working
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Here is my stencil buffer initialization code:

```cpp
// Stencil
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
// Disable stencil writing by default, to be enabled per draw cycle
glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
```

Am I doing something wrong in my texture fragment shader that is not properly discarding transparent pixels, have I not configured the stencil buffer correctly, or did I miss something somewhere else?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is my renderbuffer init code:

```cpp
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

glGenTextures(1, &texBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texBuffer);
sf::Vector2u size = tex->getSfTexture().lock()->getSize();
GLuint sizeX = size.x + (GLuint)(size.x * outlineWidth * 2), sizeY = size.y + (GLuint)(size.y * outlineWidth * 2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, sizeX, sizeY, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texBuffer, 0);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, sizeX, sizeY);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    throw new std::exception("ERROR::RENDER::INCOMPLETE_FRAMEBUFFER");
    return;
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I have updated my `render()` method and my vertex shader to represent my current code.

Comment: [The documentation states](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Stencil_Test) "if fragment tests happen early, even if the fragment shader discards the fragment, the stencil buffer can be modified." - Is there anything in your app that may be forcing early fragment tests, even though the use of the discard keyword would usually disable them?

Comment: @DMGregory The [early tests documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test) says that "if the fragment shader discards the fragment with the discard keyword, this will almost always turn off early depth tests on some hardware. Note that even conditional use of discard will mean that the FS will turn off early depth tests." This makes me think that it isn't the issue, however my use of `glStencilOp` may be problematic, but I'm not sure if it's the problem or how I could fix it if it was.

Comment: The tactical use of "almost" and "some" doesn't inspire rock-solid confidence, there. ;)

Comment: Well I do understand, but the problem is that there is no way that I know of to explicitly stop these operations if they are occuring (there is barely anything else on the page, and I am way below the version that allows for even explicit *inclusion*). I'm just hoping I can do something about this. However, I may be wrong about the `glStencilOp`, as it could also be `glStencilFunc` causing the issue. Overall, this is incredibly confusing, and I really hope OpenGL isn't doing something dumb in the background.

Comment: Can't test it now, but maybe abusing the depth buffer together with ´glStencilOp´ will help you. Therefore you need to enable depth testing. General idea: First render your sprite without stenciling enabled, BUT render it with a "reduced depth" compared to the rest of your scene. Since you are in 2d, depth does not matter for your image. Set the inputs to ´glStencilOp´ so that you only write to the stencil buffer, if the depth test is passed.  Then render it again with depth and stencil testing enabled, but with a "higher  depth. Now your stencil buffer should only contain...

Comment: set values, where your sprite is not fully transparent. Now render the upscaled outline, as usual, using the stencil mask. It might also be possible to use this technique together with some alternative render targets so that you can create the mask without polluting the depth buffer of your scene.

Comment: @wychmaster While trying to find an implementation of your idea, I have come across three possible issues. First, `glStencilOp` doesn't have a condition for the stencil test failing but the depth test passing. If the stencil test fails, it exits. The second problem is that I may end up using the z-buffer for some applications later on, so advice on alternative rendering would be appreciated. The third problem is that since the outline and the texture are on different planes, another texture could overlap the first's outline. This links back to my need for a different non-polluting solution.

Comment: First problem: I know I mentioned enabling stencil testing for the second step, but I just meant, that you should write to the stencil buffer in the second step. You don't need to discard anything using the stencil buffer. You just want to write to it, if the depth test passes, since that are only pixels, which are not covered by your sprite. So you set `sfail` and `dpfail` to `GL_KEEP` and set `dppass` to `GL_REPLACE` with an appropriate value. You are basically just copying the depth buffer to the stencil buffer.

Comment: For problem 2 and 3: Just render your sprite and outline to a texture and not to the screen. Then use this texture instead. However, if you do so, outlining for opaque sprites would theoretically be much easier and you don't need the stencil test at all. Just render your outline first, then render the sprite above it.

Comment: @wychmaster I am currently trying to use a framebuffer, and I have a question and a problem. My question: how do I change the size of a renderbuffer object? I am doing so for my texture, but I can't figure out how to do it for the renderbuffer. My problem: I currently have a texture that I write to for my framebuffer, but it is just coming out black and I can't figure out why. I will update my code with my renderbuffer usages.

Comment: @ImTheSquid Sorry, can't help you with this, since my knowledge about frame buffers is quite limited.